# Grouping observation and forming new variable

Tags: sas

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║ Obs  Type   Date      Value ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║ 1     A     Date_1     19   ║
║ 2     A     Date_2     18   ║
║ 3     A     Date_3     7    ║
║ 4     A     Date_4     3    ║
║ 5     B     Date_1     29   ║
║ 6     B     Date_2     25   ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

This is my ds

Can anyone tell me efficient way to get desired output as

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Type Date1 Value1 Date2 Value2 Date3 Value3  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ A Date_1 19 Date_2 18 Date_3 7  Date_4 29    ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

and so for other Type

Comment: You're asking for a basic proc transpose; the linked question is actually more complicated but answers this sufficiently.

Comment: I don't want my observation to be variable that i am getting by below code:

proc transpose data= x;
by type;
id Date;
var value; run;

I am unable to figure out how to bring date and it's count in front of it for each particular type.

Comment: You need two transposes or a data step and a transpose, as that question and several others here note.  You need to make 2 rows out of each row above, so you can have "date1" and "value1" as ID values.  (Also, this is not necessarily a good data structure, but that's a different point.)